# Sequential animations on HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, settimeout

guys. I'm trying to create a group of sequential "animations" through css classes on my buttons, but i keep getting a problem where all my buttons receive the effect on the same time and not one after another.

The function playAllSequence should hightlight each button one after another following the sequence present in an array.

I've already tried to put the setTimeOut function inside a closure and tried changed my declaration to let instead of var.

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance

```js
// Get number of buttons on the document
var numberOfButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length;
var collectionButtonsClicked = [];
var collectionOfRandomColors  = [];
var  buttonsColors = ["blue", "green", "red", "yellow"];
var gameTitle = document.querySelector("#level-title");

// detecting clicks on the buttons
for ( let i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".btn")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    collectionButtonsClicked.push(this.id);
    // call click animation function
    clickAnimation ();
    // Only checks when arrays have the same length so the user have to click all the sequence again
    if (collectionButtonsClicked.length === collectionOfRandomColors.length) {
      checkClick();
    }
})};

// detecting button press to start the game
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.key === "a") {
    gameTitle.innerHTML = "Game Started";
    generateRandomColor();
    playAllSequence();
  }
});

// check if the click is correct
function checkClick () {
  // if correct - Generate new color, disable buttons and play the sequence on all buttons
  let arrayRandomStringfied = JSON.stringify(collectionOfRandomColors);
  let arrayClickedStringfied = JSON.stringify(collectionButtonsClicked);

  if (arrayRandomStringfied === arrayClickedStringfied) {
    generateRandomColor();
    playAllSequence();
    console.log("acertou!")
    // erasing click array so the player has to click all the color again
    collectionButtonsClicked = [];
  } else {
    //call fail animation function
    failAnimation();
    // function to reset the arrays and the title
    restartGame();
    console.log("errou!")
  }
}

//Generate random color and return array - User will have to follow this colors
function generateRandomColor () {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  collectionOfRandomColors.push(buttonsColors[randomIndex]);
  return collectionOfRandomColors;
}

function playAllSequence () {
  // disabling all buttons
  for ( let i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".btn")[i].disabled = true;
  }

  for ( let i = 0; i < collectionOfRandomColors.length; i++ ) {
    doSetTimeOut(i);
  }

  // Enabling all buttons again
  for ( let i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".btn")[i].disabled = false;
  }
}

function doSetTimeOut (i) {
  let activeButton = document.querySelector("." + collectionOfRandomColors[i]);
  // Add pressed effect
  activeButton.classList.add("pressed");

  // Remove pressed effect after 1 second
  setTimeout(function() {
    activeButton.classList.remove("pressed")
  }, 1000);
}

function clickAnimation () {
}

function failAnimation () {
}

function restartGame () {
  collectionOfRandomColors = [];
  collectionButtonsClicked = [];
  gameTitle.innerHTML = "Press A key to Start";
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #011F3F;
}

#level-title {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin:  5%;
  color: #FEF2BF;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.btn {
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't see your sample code to animate even the first button.

If you need independent separate events to happen '1 by 1' visually, you might use a `i*1000` as a `setTimeout` second argument.

If not, here's the code doing something close to what you want to achieve, i believe. Define a function that sets the props you need (box-shadow in this example) for an element taken by index, and sets timeout for a function that will remove the props and call the first function again with the next index:

```
function animateBtnsSequence( i ){
  var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
  btns[i].style.boxShadow = '0 0 20px 1px white';

  window.setTimeout(function(){
    btns[i].style.boxShadow = '';
    if( btns[i+1] )
      animateBtnsSequence( i + 1 );
  }, 1000) 

}

function playAllSequence () {
  animateBtnsSequence( 0 );
}
```

Comment: hey @jared, tks for you answer! My animation is through addition and removal of the class "pressed". I tried your first suggestion but i keep getting overlaping animations. I'm trying to make the second animation start only after the first one ended. First button highlight, back to normal and then second one highlight and back to normal and so on. The second sugestion i get similar results to my previous code. All buttons keep highlighting together as the i progress.

Comment: Just replace `.style.boxShadow = ...` with a `.classList.add() / .classList.remove()` ;)

Comment: Yep, i did that but didnt work as i mentioned above =(

Comment: Tested with a 'pressed' CSS class, everything works as expected. Did you replace the whole `playAllSequence` with the code provided?

Comment: The codepen: https://codepen.io/JaredSpb/pen/dyJoJGX

Comment: Yes, you were right. I was selecting a specific member of the array collectionOfRandomColors. Now i'm trying to fit into my code haha. The thing is that this animation should not trigger all four buttons all the time. When the game starts (press "a"), a random color is pushed into the array collectionOfRandomColors (function generateRandomColor) and that specific button should be highlighted. When the user click on the right button, the function "checkClick" calls  generateRandomColor() and playAllSequence(). At this point i was trying to make the 2 buttons be highlithed the way your code does

Comment: Instead if using ` querySelectorAll` you might build your collection/array of elements based on criteria you need at the point and take elements from there.